# How to update table without a query for every update possible

Tags: node.js, swift, postgresql

So I heard it's bad fetching data for each cell in Swift so I'm saving notification data with all info like user picture, username, post title, etc. instead of just saving the user id and post id and fetching the data for each cell. My problem is that now I have to update the notifications in every function that updates data. Does anyone have an easier way I can update the notifications or show the updated data in my cell instead of updating it in every function? I'm using PostgreSQL and Node JS for my backend.

Answer (score 0):

"So I heard it's bad fetching data for each cell in Swift..." I'm not quite sure what that means. There's nothing specific about **Swift** that I can think of that dictates the way you fetch your data.

In general it's bad to do multiple round-trip requests over the internet for small pieces of data. The latency of each request and response adds up, making it take a lot longer to satisfy all the requests, and making the interface seem sluggish. It's generally a good idea to batch your request (Give me all the data for items 1-30". Then write your server to send the data for all the items in one response. (or send them in batches - depending on how much data each item contains, and how long it takes to send all of the responses.)

I'm also not clear on what you mean by "I have to update the notifications in every function that updates data." You're going to have to expand on that.

Comment: I'm saving a users name, post title, etc. for each notification. So when I update a users name or post title I'm going to have to update the notification as well. I have multiple functions that update a user or update a post title, etc. I'm looking for an easier way around this.

Comment: Your description is too vague for anybody to offer you meaningful advice.

Comment: Without table definitions it is difficult to be sure. But from your description it sounds as though you have a M:M relationship between Users and Posts.  If so you should not store user name nor post title in the Notification. Rather have an independent table for Users and another for Posts each with their own PK. Then Notifications stores PK the key to each of the other tables. When User data or Post data changes only the appropriate table is updated, but not Notifications.  These changes are automatically reflected (through Joins)  in Notifications. This is basic M:M resolution.